# Run time erro -2147467259: Cannot create a InternetExplorer reference

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get the following sub to run. I get an error message.

> Run time error -2147467259

```
Sub testing()

    'Cria referencia e objeto do tipo IE
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

End Sub
```

Am I missing something?
I have references to the following library:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to run Internet Explorer normally? Your code runs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx):

```
Dim MyBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set MyBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 Dim ie As Object
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

See this [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970456.aspx).

If the error persists, check if

> ```
>   IE is installed
>
>   No modal dialogs from another IE instance - if present - are open
>
>   No antivirus software is blocking it
>
>   There are no ghost IE processes hanging in Task Manager`
> ```

Comment: I think the problem is with the environment, not with code